# "rails s" doesn't work but "bundle exec rails s" works. Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

I copied the app from Github. Installed a proper version of Ruby using rbenv. I installed bundler by `gem install bundler` and ran `bundle install --path vendor/bundle`. All gems were installed in `vendor/bundle` directory in the app. Now I wonder, why `rails s` command doesn't work but `bundle exec rails s` works? The same with `rspec` command. Is this because I installed gems in `vendor/bundle` directory? I'm confused.

Also, when I run `gem list` I get only a few gems, but there are a lot of them in `vendor/bundle` directory.

Please tell me why `gem list` command doesn't see gems from `vendor/bundle` directory and why I need to run commands with `bundle exec`. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of having the bundle exec command is to look/search for the command which you want to run inside the current bundle or installed gems inside your vendor directory.

If you are running newer rails (v5) then have a look at the binstubs which copies over the command executeable in the bin directory. So that you can simply call

bin/rails server

This is the same approach which is followed by the deployment solutions which we currently have. They create a .bundle directory which eliminates the need to do bundle install everytime.

Answer (score 1):

Prefixing `bundle exec` to commands executes the command as it isn't of rails. To fix it we can simply run:
**`gem install rails`**
This will install all dependencies of rails and commands like `rails s` or `rails c` will work without `bundle exec`.